# How many different vacua really are there in the string theory landscape?

Tags: string-theory, compactification, string-theory-landscape, calabi-yau

How many different vacua are there in the string theory landscape? Different sources give different estimates: some sources talk about the number $10^{500}$, others $10^{272\ 000}$, still others say that there is an infinite number of different vacuums in the landscape (how?), and the fourth write that all these vacuums are in a swamp, and the landscape consists of only a few vacua.

Comment: @Nihar Karve thank you for editing!